# Question on bijection and permutation in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A city has recently built ten intersections. Some of these
will get traffic lights, and some of those that get traffic lights will also get
a gas station. In how many different ways can this happen?

Can anyone use bijection to solve this?
This is an example question in a combinatorics book but I couldn't understand it.

Comment: For each of the 10 intersection you have three choices: none, lights, gas...

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki The choices should be none, lights, and (lights and gas)? And how do I use bijection here

Comment: Yes ("gas" implies "gas+lights"). You can give a bijection to the cartesian product $\{1,2,3\}^{10}$, although this is not necessary to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10 intersections are independent.  I.e., what you choose at one intersection doesn't affect the choices at another.

So what's the number of possibilities at a given intersection?  Well... we can choose:

1. nothing
2. 
3. and ⛽

as you say in the comments.

And we make this choice independently for each intersection.  For example:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | ⛽ | nothing | ⛽ | ⛽ | ⛽ | nothing |  | ⛽ |

A bijection in this context is basically just another way of writing it down, so e.g. the table above is the same as $(2,2,3,1,3,3,3,1,2,3)$ where we write down the number (1, 2, or 3) corresponding to our choice.

I.e., it's equivalent to a sequence of length $10$ with elements from $\{1,2,3\}$.  So the answer to the question is the number of such sequences.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is the best answer someone gave to me on this site.